# Problemas ao fazer chamada ajax com checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tenho vários `checkbox` que vão fazer uma chamada ajax, mas só o primeiro `checkbox` é que faz a chamada.
Alguma solução nos IDs para que esta lista faça a mesma chamada ajax?

**Script:**

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function () {          
        $("#SelectDias").click(function () {

             //chamada Ajax    
            } else {

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectDias" name="SelectDias" value="Domingo" class="checkbox-inline" />
 @Html.Label("Domingo", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectDias" name="SelectDias" value="Segunda-Feira" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Segunda-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
 <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectDias" name="SelectDias" value="Terça-Feira" class="checkbox-inline"  />
@Html.Label("Terça-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectDias" name="SelectDias" value="Quarta-Feira" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Quarta-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectDias" name="SelectDias" value="Quinta-Feira" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Quinta-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectDias" name="SelectDias" value="Sexta-Feira" class="checkbox-inline"  />
@Html.Label("Sexta-Feira", new { @class = "control-label" })
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectDias" name="SelectDias" value="Sábado" class="checkbox-inline" />
@Html.Label("Sábado", new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O atributo id serve (como seu próprio nome diz) como uma identificação única para a página, não deveria ter dois elementos no mesmo frame com o mesmo id. Em vez de **$("#SelectDias")** prefira usar **$(".checkbox-inline")**, se houver algum **input** que use a classe **checkbox-inline** e ele não faz parte de **SelectDias**, cogite criar um class específico para ele, como um class **dia-da-semana**.

Comment: Perfeito, entra na função, não percebo porque é que na chamada ajax leva sempre o primeiro valor da minha primeira checkbox, ou seja "Domingo".

Comment: data: { diasPertendidos: $(".checkbox-inline").val() }

Comment: SimãoLopes nesse caso, use conforme a resposta do Diego, fazendo um $(this) para pegar o elemento que disparou o evento. O contexto this no caso de eventos no jQuery é o elemento que dispara o evento (cuidado com as pegadinhas do Event Bubbling, mas aqui não é o caso).

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

Dando um improving na resposta do Gabriel, tem que definir uma classe, como no próprio exemplo dele, **dia-da-semana**.
E dentro do seu método do click event você pega a instancia do checkbox que foi clicada para usar o valor que você selecionou:

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function () {          
        $(".dia-da-semana").click(function () {
            var instanciaCheckboxClicada = $(this);
            var valorCheckboxClicado = instanciaCheckboxClicada.val();
             //chamada Ajax passando a variavel valorCheckboxClicado
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado :)